# IS there a better way to update multiple columns of a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-update

Is there a better way to do this?

I have to `update multiple columns` of table like below:

```
UPDATE tableA
       SET column1= '1234' WHERE column1 is NOT NULL;
UPDATE tableA
       SET column2= '1234' WHERE column2 is NOT NULL;
UPDATE tableA
        SET column3= '1234' WHERE column3 IS NOT NULL OR column3<>'0000';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
UPDATE tableA
       SET column1= '1234' ,         
        column2= '1234',
        column3= '1234'
  WHERE (column2 is NOT NULL and  column1 is NOT NULL)       
          and ( column3 IS NOT NULL OR column3<>'0000')
```

Comment: That will overwrite the contents of `column2` if `column1` is null and `column2` is not

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `CASE WHEN`

```
UPDATE tableA
       SET column1= case when column1 is NOT NULL then '1234' end,
        column2= case when column2 is NOT NULL then '1234' end,
        column3= case when column3 is NOT NULL OR column3<>'0000' then '1234' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 3 `updates`, you can do:

```
UPDATE tableA
       SET column1= CASE WHEN column1 is NOT NULL THEN '1234' END, 
       SET column2= CASE WHEN column2 is NOT NULL THEN '1234' END,
       SET column3= CASE WHEN column3 IS NOT NULL OR column3<>'0000' THEN '1234' END
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your last condition should really be `column3 IS NOT NULL AND column3 <> '0000'`.  The `OR` would not include the second condition.

So I think you want:

```
UPDATE tableA
    SET column1 = (CASE WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL THEN '1234' END),
        column2 = (CASE WHEN column2 IS NOT NULL THEN '1234' END),
        column3 = (CASE WHEN column3 IS NOT NULL AND column3 <> '0000' THEN '1234' END)

    WHERE (column1 IS NOT NULL) OR
          (column2 IS NOT NULL) OR
          (column3 IS NOT NULL AND column3 <> '0000');
```

The `WHERE` clause doesn't affect the result set.  It is only there to limit the number of rows being updated.